# Problem's solving the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{1} {x^{1/3}(x+a)} dx$ where a is a constant

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, riemann-integration, substitution, partial-fractions

I found this integral

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1} {x^{1/3}(x+a)} \, \mathrm{d}x $$

as part of an example of differentiation under the integral sign in the book Advanced Calculus Explored, by Hamza E. Asamraee. There is only the hint that you can use the substitution:

$$y= x^{1/3}$$

so in the end:

$$ \mathrm{d}x = 3y^{2}\mathrm{d}y$$

And after performing the substitution the integral becomes:

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{3y^2} {y(y^3+a)} \, \mathrm{d}y = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{3y} {(y^3+a)} \, \mathrm{d}y $$

After this you can factorize the denominator in the form

$$y^3+a = (y+a^{1/3})(y^2-a^{1/3}y+a^{2/3})$$

and use partial fractions so that the integral becomes:

$$ -\frac{1}{a^{1/3}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y+a^{1/3}} + \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{y+a}{y^2-a^{1/3}y+a^{2/3}} \, \mathrm{d}y $$

And the problem is that these two integrals diverge but in the book or even in wolfram alpha the result is:

$$ \frac{2\pi}{a^{1/3}\sqrt{3}} $$

But I don't know if I made a mistake in the substitution or in which part, so I request for help :c

Comment: $y^3+a=(y+a^{1/3})(y^2-ya^{1/3}+a^{2/3})$

Comment: Well i see that but like i said, $a$ is a constant, so still no actual change
My problem is that the last integrals diverge

Comment: @Daniel Perez I think haman_Abdallah is saying that you applied the formula for the sum of two cubes incorrectly.

Comment: You split the convergent integral into two divergent integrals. It is similar to writing $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\bigl( \sqrt{x^2+1} - x \bigr) \stackrel{\text{??}}= \lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{x^2+1} - \lim_{x\to\infty}x. $$ The convergence of the limit in the left-hand side hinges on the cancellation of divergent parts of the two terms, so you cannot split the limit into two parts.

Comment: But then how can i find the integral?

Comment: There are other ways of avoiding infinities in this computation: Return to the basic and compute the definite integral: $$\int_{0}^{R}\frac{3y}{y^3+a}\,\mathrm{d}y = \frac{1}{a^{1/3}}\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{R^2-a^{1/3}R+a^{2/3}}}{R+a^{1/3}}\right)-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{a^{1/3}}\arctan\left(\frac{1-\frac{2R}{a^{1/3}}}{\sqrt{3}}\right)+\frac{\pi}{2a^{1/3}\sqrt{3}}$$

Comment: You cannot decompose this improper integral as a sum of two improper integrals unless both improper integrals in the sum are known to converge. I suggest you evaluate the indefinite integral $\int\frac{3ydy}{y^3 +a}$ first, then plug in the bounds.  (You'll have to combine some logarithms)

Comment: 1. ${x \over a} \mapsto x.\quad$ 2. $t = {1 \over 1 + x}.\quad$ 3. Beta Function.

Comment: Or Ramanujan Master Theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

WLOG $a=1$ (you can rescale the variable).

$$\int\left(\frac{y+1}{y^2-y+1}-\frac{1}{y+1}\right)dy=\int\left(\frac{y-\frac12}{y^2-y+1}+\frac{\frac32}{y^2-y+1}-\frac{1}{y+1}\right)dy
\\=\ln\frac{\sqrt{y^2-y+1}}{y+1}+\int \frac{\frac32}{y^2-y+1}dy.$$

The first term will cancel out, and the remaining integral is solved by an arc tangent.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
This is a simple application of
*Ramanujan's Master Theorem*:
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\left.\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\dd x \over x^{1/3}\pars{x + a}}\,\right\vert_{\,a\ >\ 0}} =
{1 \over a^{1/3}}\int_{0}^{\infty}
{x^{\color{red}{2/3} - 1} \over x^{1/3}\pars{1 + x}}\,\dd x
\end{align}
Note that
$\ds{{1 \over 1 + x} = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}
\color{red}{\Gamma\pars{1 + k}}{\pars{-x}^{k} \over k!}}$. Then,
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\left.\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\dd x \over x^{1/3}\pars{x + a}}\,\right\vert_{\,a\ >\ 0}} =
{1 \over a^{1/3}}\,\Gamma\pars{\color{red}{2 \over 3}}
\Gamma\pars{1 - \color{red}{2 \over 3}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over a^{1/3}}\,{\pi \over \sin\pars{\pi/3}} =
{1 \over a^{1/3}}\,{\pi \over \root{3}/2} =
\bbx{{2\root{3} \over 3}\,\pi\,a^{-1/3}} \\ &
\end{align}